# Put request with express and axios is throwing 404 (Using react)

Tags: reactjs, express, axios, put

/*Java script file*/

```
 function updateArticle()
    {
        console.log("Article"+Id); // ID is fine
        axios.put("http://localhost:3000/update/"+Id,Article)
            .then(res => res.data)
            .catch(err => console.error("Wasn't able to update property.", err))
        setArticle({title:"",content:""});
    }
```

/* Routes file */

```
router.route("/update/:id").put((req,res) => {

const Article = {
    title:req.body.title,
    content:req.body.content
}
console.log(Article);
newArticle.findByIdAndUpdate({_id:req.params.id},{$set:Article},(req,res,err) =>
    {
        !err ? console.log("Article updated") : console.log("error")
    })
})
```

/* console */
[Error i was getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z18Zd.jpg)

I could not find where the error is getting even the put route exists in the routes file it is giving the 404 error.

Comment: Does the article with the requested id exist in the db?

Comment: yes the article with the requested id exits in the db